# Angular static provider bootstrap not overriding application root provider

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-bootstrap, angular-providers

Using Angular 6.0.3

Have a third party Azure Adal wrapper that is imported into the root application module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ....
  <3rd party module>.forRoot(<configuration object here>)
  ....
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[third party module definition]

```
@NgModule()
export class <3rd party module> {
  static forRoot(@Inject(<thing to override>) config): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: <3rd party module>,
      providers: [ 
        ... 
        { provide: <thing to override>, useValue: config } 
        ... 
      ]
    }
  };
}
```

The configuration passed to `forRoot` is used as the `useValue` argument for a provider.  Thought I could override the provided object during the bootstrap of the module:

```
<fetch configuration form server>
.then(json => 
  platformBrowserDynamic(
    [ { provide: <thing to override>, useJson: json } ]
  )
  .boostrapModule(AppModule)
);
```

However, the static provider must be earlier in the bubble-up order for resolving providers in Angular since the provided object is always the one deriving configuration object passed in the NgModule decorator at the app level (i.e. the one used in the static `forRoot` call).

Tried forking the 3rd party library adding **multi** to the provide directives and letting dependents swallow an array instead.  But that doesn't seem to work either.  The provide directive from the static provider when bootstrapping is ignored totally (i.e. never added to the multi array).

Any ideas?